# Error TS2339: Property 'router' does not exist on type 'HomePage'

Tags: angular, wordpress, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am constantly getting the following error:

```
[ng] ERROR in src/app/home/home.page.ts(34,10): error TS2339: Property 'router' does not exist on type 'HomePage'.
```

I am trying to couple **Wordpress with Ionic 4** and so far I managed to fetch the recent posts from my site. **Now I want to make these clickable and navigate to them**, but I am getting the error mentioned above because of this snippet in my `home.page.ts`

```
  openPost(postId) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/post/' + postId);
  }
```

Full page:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { WordPressRestapiService, Post } from '../services/wordpress-restapi.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  categoryId: number;
  private posts : Post[] = [];

  constructor(
    public loadingController: LoadingController,
    private wordpressService: WordPressRestapiService) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create();
    await loading.present();

    this.loadPosts().subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {
      this.posts = posts
      loading.dismiss();
    });
  }

  loadPosts() {
    return this.wordpressService.getRecentPosts(this.categoryId);
  }
  openPost(postId) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/post/' + postId);
  }
}
```

I have tried removing "this" as well, but nothing that I could find on SO worked for me. Anyone any idea?

Comment: You need to inject the router in the constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inject the router in the constructor

```
constructor(
  public loadingController: LoadingController,
  private wordpressService: WordPressRestapiService,
  private router: Router) { }
```

Comment: Ah, that simple?! Thank you very much! Newbie here regarding Angular and Ionic, which is obvious now :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare the router variable in your constructor.

```
constructor( private router: Router ){
}
```